# Getting "Missing Artifacts" while they are exist in .m2

Tags: maven

In my setting.xml from .m2 folder, the following configs are applied to get jar files from local nexus repository:

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
        <url>http://192.168.0.172:9090/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

In my pom.xml, an external repository declared to get jar files not presented in central repository:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snasphot</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Despite of the fact that these so called "missing artifacts" are existed in their corresponding folder in .m2, but I always get

> Missing artifact ....

What is wrong with my configurations?
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Can you show the full error messsage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I just figured it out. Having deleted files excluding jar file from corresponding folder, and then updating maven project solved the problem.

Comment: hi khoda bakhsh ! ;)

in my case i removed `_remote.repositories` and `xxxx.pom.lastestUpdated` files and it fixed

Answer (score 0):

The configuration looks ok. But something must be going on...

If you delete those snapshot artifacts from your local repository and retry (for ex: `mvn dependency:go-offline`) do you see an attempt is made to download the artifact from https://repo.spring.io/snapshot ?

The additional repository seems to contain snapshots but the  are not enabled for that repository. But I'm not sure whats the default. The artifacts may be not found because of the update policy. They are locally available but too old so maven tries to update them but fails (have you tried mvn -X ? that may give an indication what fails when resolving those artifacts).

What may be an option is to add the spring snapshots repo to your nexus (snapshot repo enabled) and set the mirrorOf in settings xml to `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>`.
The mirror of central only might was intended so: just an experiment :)

It is always a good thing to verify the settings maven actually sees are the ones you think they are:

```
mvn help:effective-settings

mvn help:effective-pom
```